# What is the best practice to handle dangerous characters in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best practice to handle dangerous characters in asp.net?
see example: [asp.net sign up form](http://screencast.com/t/HhnpsBjn)

Should you:

1. use a JavaScript to prevent them from entering it into the textbox in the 1st place?
2. have a general function that does a find and replace on the server side?

The problem with #1, is it will increase page load time.

Comment: Why would a character be considered "dangerous"? Are you talking about stopping XSS attacks, Sql Injection attacks, or making sure no one ever types `þ`?

Comment: The main problem with number 1 isn't the load time, it's that anyone can bypass it. Client-side validation for things like this should be for user experience and not for actual security.

Comment: Wait 'til they write as their name `Robert'); DROP TABLE Persons;--`? :-)

Comment: @xanatos That's a different type of dangerous character, though, which is properly handled simply by using query parameters to SQL statements / procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution number 1 won't increment load time by much.

You should ALWAYS use solution number 2 along with solution number one, because users can turn off javascript in their browsers.

Answer (score 9):

ASP .NET handles potentially dangerous characters for you, by default since ASP .NET 2.0. From [Request Validation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx):

> Request validation is a feature in ASP.NET that examines an HTTP
>   request and determines whether it contains potentially dangerous
>   content. In this context, potentially dangerous content is any HTML
>   markup or JavaScript code in the body, header, query string, or
>   cookies of the request. ASP.NET performs this check because markup or
>   code in the URL query string, cookies, or posted form values might
>   have been added for malicious purposes.
>
> Request validation helps prevent this kind of attack. If ASP.NET
>   detects any markup or code in a request, it throws a "potentially
>   dangerous value was detected" error and stops page processing.

Perhaps the most important bit of this is that it happens on the server; regardless of the client accessing your application they can not just turn of JavaScript to work around it.

Comment: Top answer. Put some client side validation on top of this, just to make it user friendly.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I 100% agree. Client-side validation prevents the need to post back to the server and creates a more responsive feeling UI. In conjunction with the built-in request validation it is a complete solution.

Comment: Exactly. It's a win-win situation.

Comment: The built-in validation is not secure. It is a best-effort tool.

Comment: Also, you can no longer accept special chars like '. That's unacceptable for many human input cases.

Comment: @usr I've yet to see the built-in validation fail on an apostrophe or extended ASCII characters. While one probably *could* built a better mousetrap that's a whole lot of reinventing to do. For 99% of general use cases I'd stand by the built-in implementation.

Comment: @Yuck if it doesn't fail on that, what good is it?! It lets dangerous chars through and you have to encode the output to avoid security problems. This tool is a defense in depth measure meant to address applications that are sloppily programmed (no security mindset).

Comment: The only problem of this solution is that before or later perhaps you have to disable it in a page (perhaps because the user must be able to insert math formulas, or because the user must be able to format simple HTML), and from there there is an entry point for **the evil**.

Answer (score 2):

You accept them like regular characters on the write-side. When rendering you encode your output. You have to encode it anyway regardless of security so that you can display special characters.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best practice to handle dangerous characters in asp.net?

I did not watch the screencast you link to (questions should be self-contained anyway), but **there are no dangerous characters**. It all depends on the context. Take Stack Overflow for example, it lets me input the characters `Dangerous!'); DROP TABLE Questions--`. Nothing dangerous there.

ASP.NET itself will do its best to prevent malicious input at the HTTP level: it won't let any user access files like `web.config` or files outside your web root.

As soon as **you** start doing something with user input, it's up to you. There's no silver bullet, no one rule that fits them all. If you're going to display the user input as HTML, you'll have to make sure you only allow harmless markup tags without any scriptable attributes. If you're allowing users to upload images, make sure only images get uploaded. If you're going to send input to an RDBMS, be sure to escape characters that have meaning for the database manipulation language.

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS validate input on the server, this should not even be a discussion, just do it!

Client-side validation is just eye candy for the user, but the server is where it counts!

Comment: It's also an usability thing, users can get feedback on their input without submitting the form.

Comment: @anakata - I agree to a certain degree, but server-side validation can provide visual feedback as well. I get what you are saying though.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that

> ASP .NET handles potentially dangerous characters for you, by default since ASP .NET 2.0. From Request Validation in ASP.NET:

is like thinking that a solid door will keep a thief out. It won't. It will only slow him. You have to know what are the most common vectors and what are the possible solutions. You must comprehend that every EVERY **EVERY** variable (field/property) you write in an HTML/CSS/Javascript is a potential attack vector that must be sanitized (through the use of appropriate libraries, like some methods included in newer MVC.NET, or at least the `<%: %>` of ASP.NET 4.0), no exceptions, every EVERY **EVERY** query you execute is a potential attach vector that must be sanitized through the exclusive use of ORM and parameterized queries, no exceptions. No passwords must be saved in the db. And tons of other similar things. It isn't very difficult, but laziness, complacence, ignorance will make it harder (if not nearly impossible). If it isn't you that will introduce **the hole** then it's the programmer on your left, or the programmer on your right. There is not hope.